# Unable to run Google App Engine PHP on port 8080

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I'm trying to use google app engine php sdk .
I'm reading this documentation `https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/gettingstarted/helloworld` .

It says I should go to `http://localhost:8080/` to see my helloworld script .

But the browser encounters the following server error :

```
Server error
The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost:8080/. It may be down     for maintenance or configured incorrectly.
Here are some suggestions:
Reload this webpage later.
HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.
```

I am using google chrome on Ubuntu 12.04 .

This is my `helloworld.php`

```
<?php
echo "Hello World !";
?>
```

And my `app.yaml` :

```
application: helloworld
version: 1
runtime: php
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /.*
script: helloworld.php
```

Comment: Did you start the stand alone development server?

Comment: So what is the PHP code on that url? That might have an error

Comment: @Paul What do you mean by standalone development server ??

I started the server as described in the documentation as :
`google_appengine/dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=php-5.4.15/installdir/bin/php-cgi appengine/helloworld/
`

Comment: @Hanky Panky

The code in the PHP file is just to echo `Hello World!`

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  The solution was simple.
I hadn't installed apache server on my ubuntu.
After installing the Apache server (`sudo apt-get install apache2`) the `localhost:8080` worked as expected.

P.S. Google didn't mention anything about installing the Apache server in the "Installing the SDK" part of their documentation.

Comment: You should NOT need to install apache for dev_appserver or GAE SDK to work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Looks like  you installed 5.4. GAE supports only 5.5
2. have you done GAE run time extension set up ?

   ```
   python dev_appserver.py --php_executable_path=/usr/bin/php-cgi   **--php_gae_extension_path=/var/www/html/appengine-php-extension/modules/gae_runtime_module.so** /var/www/html/project
   ```

   See: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-php-extension
3. If above points are ok, then it might me php code error . just debug it line by line.